# Node-red "no response object"

Tags: node.js, node-red

I'm trying to create a http get node that takes form data and then creates an http post to another web site using a rest API.  I'm able to get the http call to return the correct payload however the http response node is giving a "no response object" error in the debug tab and the client never returns.  Do I specifically need to do something to pass the response object so the call sends the correct response object to the http response node?

Here is the flow:
[{"id":"7011e7a9.8fee18","type":"http request","name":"","method":"use","ret":"obj","url":"","x":499,"y":84,"z":"51693a88.ae96c4","wires":[["efea497c.1015b8"]]},{"id":"589f2a18.a760d4","type":"function","name":"","func":"var myprocess = context.global.process;\nmyprocess.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = \"0\";\nvar dev_url = \"https://website.com:22411/central/api/qracore/browses?browseId=mfg:gp239\";\n \nvar msg = {\n    \"method\" : \"GET\",\n    \"url\" : dev_url,\n    \"headers\" : {\n        \"Authorization\": \"Basic abWZnQHFhZC5jb206=\",\n        \"Origin\" : \"mybox.com\"\n    }\n};\n \nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":323,"y":154,"z":"51693a88.ae96c4","wires":[["7011e7a9.8fee18"]]},{"id":"9f65b624.609a48","type":"debug","name":"","active":true,"console":"false","complete":"payload","x":810,"y":211,"z":"51693a88.ae96c4","wires":[]},{"id":"38e4c04d.c71b4","type":"http in","name":"","url":"/workOrders","method":"get","swaggerDoc":"","x":152,"y":190,"z":"51693a88.ae96c4","wires":[["589f2a18.a760d4"]]},{"id":"e5ee54b2.1a11a8","type":"http response","name":"","x":770,"y":96,"z":"51693a88.ae96c4","wires":[]},{"id":"efea497c.1015b8","type":"function","name":"","func":"var newMsg = { payload: msg.payload };\nreturn newMsg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":582,"y":214,"z":"51693a88.ae96c4","wires":[["e5ee54b2.1a11a8","9f65b624.609a48"]]}]

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Please format your code properly. It is unreadable.

Answer (score 8):

The key is to pass it from node to the other.  You do that by using the req and the res from the msg to pass to the output.

```
var newMsg = { payload: msg.payload };
//return [msg, newMsg];

newMsg.user = msg.req.body["user"];
newMsg.req  = msg.req;
newMsg.res = msg.res;

return newMsg;
```